# Partially specialized template instantiation in C++ disregards compile-time error

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

The following code compiles (and runs) just fine, even though I would expect it to produce a compile-time error:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
struct is_int {
    static const bool value = false;
};

template<>
struct is_int<int> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// General template definition with default second type parameter (void)
template <typename A, typename B = void>
struct Foo {
    static const int i = 42;
};

// Partially specialized template definition with possibly
// undefined second parameter
template<typename A>
struct Foo<A, typename enable_if<is_int<A>::value>::type > {
    static const int i = 56;
};


int main() {
    cout << Foo<bool>::i << endl; // Outputs '42'
    cout << Foo<int>::i << endl; // Outputs '56'
    return 0;
}
```

The `enable_if` template inside the partial specialization of struct `Foo` does only define the member type `type` if the first argument is the value `true`. See the [reference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if).

So, when the first line in the `main` function instantiates template `Foo`, what exactly does the compiler do? Clearly, when it tries to match the partial specialization, it would run into an error (because `type` is not defined).

Does it simply discard this choice in order to avoid an error?

Comment: There's no such thing like _partial template specialization/instantiation_ in c++?!?

Comment: Sounds like you're talking about "SFINAE" behavior, which is expected

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Corrected (hopefully) the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are experiencing is the basic of template introspection and it is called [SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error).

Simply put: when a template parameter substitution fails, it doesn't throw but simply "*move on*" and grab the next candidate that doesn't result in a deduction failure. This can be useful to do some compile-time analysis.

Boost's [enable_if](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html) is base on SFINAE.

Comment: The current standard also has [`enable_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if). We should abandon this behavior to refer c++03 as equivalent for the [tag:c++] tag _'being the standard'_! (there's no mention of boost in the OP BTW)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sometimes it's good to remember where things came from ;)